# External script hash with 'strict-dynamic' requires "integrity" attribute on script tag?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I'm working on a site's [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), specifically the [`strict-dynamic`](https://content-security-policy.com/strict-dynamic/) keyword.

My [test site](https://github.com/jonbri/csp-test) has two files:

*index.html:*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>csp-test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>csp-test</h1>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*index.js:*

```js
console.log('foo');
```

I'm looking into using the hash-based approach to allow the script.

Here is how I'm generating the hash in a node script:

```js
const input = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/index.js");
crypto.createHash("sha256").update(input, 'utf8').digest('base64')
```

and here is the result for `index.js`: `1kOLrDKT3TBiHLcnxiGsc7HF/lyVJKLhoZDSn0UwCfo=`

With this hash, I update my CSP config to:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-1kOLrDKT3TBiHLcnxiGsc7HF/lyVJKLhoZDSn0UwCfo=' 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'
```

When I include this value as a response header (using the ModHeader Chrome extension) with this name `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` I still get an error in the console:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:5000/index.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'sha256-1kOLrDKT3TBiHLcnxiGsc7HF/lyVJKLhoZDSn0UwCfo=' 'unsafe-inline'". 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I can make this error go away by using setting the `integrity` attribute on my script tag:

```html
<script integrity="sha256-1kOLrDKT3TBiHLcnxiGsc7HF/lyVJKLhoZDSn0UwCfo=" src="./index.js"></script>
```

My question is: **Why did I need to add the `integrity` attribute?**
I'm not seeing it mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) and needing to add this attribute would further complicate our build process.
Is there an alternative to needing to specify this attribute?

Comment: Sidenote: You might want to get rid of 'unsafe-inline' from your CSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did I need to add the integrity attribute? I'm not seeing it
> mentioned in the documentation and needing to add this attribute would
> further complicate our build process.

MDN contains only common things to explain how CSP works. All the nitty-gritty is in [CSP spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash)
Usage of `'hash-value'` token assumes that external script already has the `integrity=` attribute (scripts from third-party CDNs). For own scripts it's easier to use `'nonce-value'` token.
Moreover, Firefox [does not support](http://csplite.com/csp/test161/#bug_Firefox_hash-value) 'hash-value' for allowing external scripts, only for internal ones. Safari - [too](http://csplite.com/csp/test216/#safari).

> Is there an alternative to needing to specify this attribute?

No way, unfortunately. Only built-in scripts `<script>...</script>` does not require `integrity=` attr and will be auto allowed if their hashes contains in the `script-src` directive.

> I'm working on a site's Content Security Policy, specifically the
> strict-dynamic keyword.

Be careful, Safari still does [not support](http://csplite.com/csp224/#bug_Safari_strict-dynamic) `'strict-dynamic'`.

> Here is how I'm generating the hash in a node script:
>
> > const input = `fs.readFileSync("/path/to/index.js");
> > crypto.createHash("sha256").update(input, 'utf8').digest('base64')

Content of external scripts [does not need](http://csplite.com/csp24/#diff_inline_external) to be converted to UTF8 before hashing, only inline scripts have to be transcoded.
Also CSP spec requires all '**-**' characters replace with '**+**', and all '**_**' characters replace with '**/**' in the hashes **value**. And after that 'sha256-' prefix is added.

Comment: How would I alter `crypto.createHash("sha256").update(input, 'utf8').digest('base64')` to prevent the conversion to UTF8? The [example](http://csplite.com/csp24/#hash_nodeJS) doesn't seem to actually take in the input (`const input = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/script.js");crypto.createHash("sha256").digest('base64');`)?

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right, `update()` is erroneously missing. It should be `crypto.createHash('sha256').update(input).digest('base64');`. Fithermore, *Encoding* [is ignored](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#crypto_hash_update_data_inputencoding) for *Buffer data type* (NodeJS is smarty for that). [Here](https://repl.it/@egranty/Test-of-crypto#index.js) is the sandboxed working example.