# CSP violation with hash

Tags: content-security-policy

I have a JS file which that us being imported by

```
<script src="https://example.com/file.js"/>
```

and I have a CSP policy with the hash that is generated when I paste the output of this file in: https://report-uri.com/home/hash

But I still get an error saying it violates this SHA256 checksum. What am I doing wrong? isn't that suppose to have the checksum of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash for external files is only supported in CSP level 3, https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#external-hash. Many browsers still only support level 2.

For CSP level 2 browsers you will need to include the actual host names such as example.com. You can achieve the same whitelisting of script with subresource integrity (SRI hash).

Comment: I'm running on latest chrome. Not sure why it still happens. my CSP policy also contains 'strict-dynamic'.

Answer (score 0):

1. `report-uri.com` do **not** calculate hashes for external scripts, it's intended for strings only. Therefore it just calc hash from string of file_name entered but not from file content.
   Right hashes for external files can be calculated, for example, [here](http://csplite.com/csp/sha/).
   And do not fogtet to add the `integrity=` attribute to `<script src='...' integrity='...'>`.
2. Be careful, Mozilla Firefox does [not support hash-sources](http://csplite.com/csp/test161/#bug_Firefox_hash-value) for **external** scripts, but for inline only.
   Safari - the same as Firefox (at least Safari 12.1.1).
3. The `'strict-dynamic'` token is not [widely supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977134/external-script-hash-with-strict-dynamic-requires-integrity-attribute-on-scr/64980699#64980699) too as on December 2020